# To print log file with out put of cron job scheduled for a sql block - with Date and time (all the executions of cron)

Tags: linux, sql, oracle

I have a shell script which executes a pl/sql block, I'm printing output to output file but it's not keeping old information and not displaying time and date when the script was executed.

My script below.

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -s $DATABASE > output << EOSQL 

SET FEEDBACK ON

declare

veventSource varchar2(20);
verrorcode integer;
verrorMessage varchar2(255);

begin

for rec in (select substr(customer,3) as pid, substr(account_num,1,2) as 
countrycode from account 
where substr(account_num,1,2) = substr(account_num,3,2)
and customernot in (select customer from custsource) )

loop

veventSource := rec.countrycode||'_'||rec.pid;
IPGDDL.LINKTOAC(rec.countrycode,rec.LID,veventSource,
'01-JAN-1971',null,'F',null,null,null,null,null,verrorcode,verrorMessage);
dbms_output.put_line(verrorcode);
dbms_output.put_line(verrorMessage);
commit;

end loop;

end;
/
EXIT

EOSQL
```

After executing the script I do have a log file, which only prints `PL/SQL Procedure completed successfully`.

I want sql output to be printed in output.txt file in the directory, with date and time when cron job run with this script, and also keep all the old data in the log.

Can anyone help on this please.

Answer (score 1):

To have `sqlplus` print out the output of your script you can use:

```
set serveroutput on
```

From [SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699298):

> Controls whether to display output (that is, `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`) of stored procedures or PL/SQL blocks in SQL*Plus.

To have the output *appended* to `output.txt` you may use the `>>` redirection operator:

```
sqlplus -s $DATABASE >>output.txt << EOSQL
...
```

The `>` operator truncates the file on its right hand, if it exists, to a zero size.
Reference: [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Appending-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) (assuming Bash based on the `#!/bin/bash` shebang of your script).

To include the date and time of execution of your cron jobs you may add

```
date >>output.txt
```

to your script, before the invocation of `sqlplus`.
Refer to the documentation for the `date` command installed on your system (e.g. `man date`) for the date format options available to you.

Alternatively, you may drop the `-s` option to `sqlplus`: its output will then include a timestamp, saving you the need for any further command to record the execution date/time (but it will also include a number of possibly unwanted messages).